# How to determine if data has been written into a variable within a structure

Tags: c, compiler-errors, comparison

As I've been teaching myself how to program in C for the past few months, I'm still an amateur and on occasion I'll run into a wall while attempting a simple task. In this case, I'm unable to determine how to ask if data has been written into a variable within a structure.

Currently, I've bypassed this by initializing an integer to zero that will increment to one upon a TRUE if statement result and then ask if it's zero or one. I'm sure that this is frowned upon by the programming community. Here is a bit of code that will not compile because of the incompatibility of comparing pointers (NULL) with the variable in the structure. Can someone please tell me how I can do this properly? Thanks in advance!!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct alpha
{
    int coordinates[3];
} alpha;

typedef struct nulltest
{
    struct alpha *a;
} nulltest;

void assign(struct nulltest *nt)
{
    int n, m=20, x=0, y=1, z=2;
    nt->a=malloc(m*sizeof(struct alpha));

    for(n=0; n<m; n++){
        nt->a[n].coordinates[0]=x;
        nt->a[n].coordinates[1]=y;
        nt->a[n].coordinates[2]=z;

        x++;
        y++;
        z++;

        if(nt->a[n].coordinates[0]==NULL){
            printf("OH NO! No data!");
            break;
        }
        else printf("Great! Data assigned!");
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct nulltest nt;

    assign(&nt);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the set of possible values for the variable you want to test you need to take one and define it as the "invalid value" value. Always initalise this variable to this value.

If for example you know a coordinate could not become negative define `-1` as "invalid value" value. Or if negativ values are allowed use the most negative possible `INT_MIN`.

```
...

/* Prior to assignment initialise all vars to a well-defined value. */
for(n=0; n<m; n++)
{
    nt->a[n].coordinates[0]=INT_MIN;
    nt->a[n].coordinates[1]=INT_MIN;
    nt->a[n].coordinates[2]=INT_MIN;
}

/* Do the assignment. */
for(n=0; n<m; n++)
{
    /* Some logic assigning values to nt->a[n].coordinates[] 
       (or not) out of the range INT_MIN+1 ..INT_MAX. */
}

/* Test whether all initial value had been overwritten. */
for(n=0; n<m; n++)
{
    if (
      INT_MIN == nt->a[n].coordinates[0] ||
      INT_MIN == nt->a[n].coordinates[1] ||
      INT_MIN == nt->a[n].coordinates[2]
    )
    {
      printf("OH NO! No data at index %d\n" , n);
    }
}

...
```

If you need each and every possibe value out of the set of possible value you then indeed need to do it as you did, defining a flag whcih indicates whether the variable had been set.

Comment: Thanks! You've made it clear, though let me ask you about your last point. One thing that I've considered previously was in fact to add a flag to my structure. I was told I need to use a class rather than a structure or create a function that would do just this. I'd like to preserve efficiency however. Is it simple to add some char flag to a structure that would indicate if the structure's allocated memory has been accessed?

Comment: @MikeM: In C there are no classes. If your code manages all and every access to the structure in question, then yes, it is simple.

Answer (score 1):

You have to test that if like `nt->a==NULL` for the memory is allocated or not.

`nt->a[n]->coordinates[0] == NULL` You  have to test it whether the value is assigned or not like `nt->a[n]->coordinates[0]==0`.

So the error is occurred due to the mismatched of the pointer comparison with integer.

Here NULL is the pointer and nt->a[n]->coordinates[0]  is integer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to write some data and then to read it back:

```
nt->a[n].coordinates[0]=1234;
```

and:

```
if(nt->a[n].coordinates[0]!=1234){
    printf("OH NO! No data!");
    break;
}
```

But this is pointless. In fact, here you are testing whether your hardware and compiler is correct.

I think you might check the whole structure. See Chandrus post for this...

Answer (score 0):

To add to what *Chandru* said, which actually answers your question, there is no test to validate the `No data` question. *nt->a[n].coordinates[0]* will always have some data cause it is pointing to some memory location. The propper test for your logic is *is my data correct?* and the comparisson should be

```
if(nt->a[n].coordinates[0] == x - 1){
    printf("OH NO! Data incorrect!");
    break;
}
else printf("Great! Data correct!");
```